# Conditional Formatting for CF Report Builder

Tags: coldfusion, report

I have a date field in a ColdFusion Report (cfr file) and I need to add some conditional formatting to it.  When the `DatePart(Month)` is GT 8 then the background color should be grey, otherwise white.

I tried adding an `IIF` expression but not sure where it goes.

```
IIF(field!DatePart(mm,query.birthdate) GT 8, "#CCCCCC", "#FFFFFF")
```

Comment: Can you provide your current code?

Comment: IIF(field!DatePart(mm,query.birthdate) GT 8, "#CCCCCC", "#FFFFFF")